# How to show json data with column name in php

Tags: php, json

i have some `JSON` data
i am able to retrieve data out of it  but i want data to be displayed with columns
this the `JSON`

```
{"ObjectId":43,"ObjectName":"MEGA MELA","ObjectTitle":"Event Created by API","ObjectDescription":"NEW EVENT BY API","ObjectLabel":"","ObjectTypeId":33,"MaxFieldsExpected":5,"ObjectValueType":null,"ObjectControlType":"","IsDeleted":true,"CreatedDate":"2019-05-22T07:56:03.767","CreatedBy":null,"EditedDate":null,"EditedBy":null,"DeletedDate":null},{"ObjectId":44,"ObjectName":"Event x11","ObjectTitle":"Event Created by API","ObjectDescription":"NEW EVENT BY API","ObjectLabel":"","ObjectTypeId":33,"MaxFieldsExpected":5,"ObjectValueType":null,"ObjectControlType":"","IsDeleted":true,"CreatedDate":"2019-05-23T00:33:50.7","CreatedBy":null,"EditedDate":null,"EditedBy":null,"DeletedDate":null}]}
```

here is what i am doing right now

```
  $jsonData = json_decode($data, TRUE);

  foreach ($jsonData as $d) {
    foreach ($d as $ins) {  
  echo "<h3>".$ins['ObjectName']."</h3>";
  echo "<h3>".$ins['ObjectDescription']."</h3>";
    }
}
```

**OutPut:**

**MEGA MELA

NEW EVENT BY API

Event x11

NEW EVENT BY API**

i want it in this format

```
ObjectId  | ObjectName | ObjectTitle           | ObjectDescription | ObjectLabel | ObjectTypeId | MaxFieldsExpected | ObjectValueType | ObjectControlType | IsDeleted | CreatedDate | CreatedBy | EditedDate |  EditedBy
43        |  MEGA MELA |  Event Created by API | NEW EVENT BY API | ..............................................................................
```

above i am getting data with help of array key now i want extracting `keys` from `JSON` like `ObjectId` or `ObjectName` making them header of table and showing all the data in columns

Comment: `foreach ($array as $KEY => $value)`

Comment: where should i use this foreach ?

Comment: can you please show with above example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the above example, you can use the `key` to print the filed name and `value` will be the data.

here we can loop the field names first to create the heading

I am using table here.

```
<table>
 <?php foreach ($d as $ins) { ?>

  //printing field heads
  <tr>
  <?php 
   foreach ($ins as $key=>$value) {  
     echo "<td><h3>".$key."</h3></td>";
   } ?>
  </tr>

  //printing value row
  <tr>
  <?php
   foreach ($ins as $key=>$value) {  
     echo "<td><h3>".$value."</h3></td>";
   } ?>
  </tr>
  } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Used an old gist for `array2table` from here : http://www.aidanlister.com/2004/04/converting-arrays-to-human-readable-tables/

```
<?php
function array2table($array, $recursive = false, $null = '&nbsp;')
{
    // Sanity check
    if (empty($array) || !is_array($array)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!isset($array[0]) || !is_array($array[0])) {
        $array = array($array);
    }
    // Start the table
    $table = "<table>\n";
    // The header
    $table .= "\t<tr>";
    // Take the keys from the first row as the headings
    foreach (array_keys($array[0]) as $heading) {
        $table .= '<th>' . $heading . '</th>';
    }
    $table .= "</tr>\n";
    // The body
    foreach ($array as $row) {
        $table .= "\t<tr>" ;
        foreach ($row as $cell) {
            $table .= '<td>';
            // Cast objects
            if (is_object($cell)) { $cell = (array) $cell; }
            if ($recursive === true && is_array($cell) && !empty($cell)) {
                // Recursive mode
                $table .= "\n" . array2table($cell, true, true) . "\n";
            } else {
                $table .= (strlen($cell) > 0) ?
                    htmlspecialchars((string) $cell) :
                $null;
            }
            $table .= '</td>';
        }
        $table .= "</tr>\n";
    }
    $table .= '</table>';
    return $table;
}
$data ='[{"ObjectId":43,"ObjectName":"MEGA MELA","ObjectTitle":"Event Created by API","ObjectDescription":"NEW EVENT BY API","ObjectLabel":"","ObjectTypeId":33,"MaxFieldsExpected":5,"ObjectValueType":null,"ObjectControlType":"","IsDeleted":true,"CreatedDate":"2019-05-22T07:56:03.767","CreatedBy":null,"EditedDate":null,"EditedBy":null,"DeletedDate":null},{"ObjectId":44,"ObjectName":"Event x11","ObjectTitle":"Event Created by API","ObjectDescription":"NEW EVENT BY API","ObjectLabel":"","ObjectTypeId":33,"MaxFieldsExpected":5,"ObjectValueType":null,"ObjectControlType":"","IsDeleted":true,"CreatedDate":"2019-05-23T00:33:50.7","CreatedBy":null,"EditedDate":null,"EditedBy":null,"DeletedDate":null}]';
$jsonData = json_decode($data, TRUE);
echo array2table($jsonData);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/0n27Y

Answer (score 0):

Second foreach should look like: `foreach ($d as $key => $ins)` then at `$key` variable you get your indexes.